# Linq query cannot convert double to double?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

**I have two table:**

1. AllPhonBills
2. PersonalNumbers

I want to query all records from first table where the numbers exist in PersonalNumbers table or list.

**Bellow is my code:**

```
var GetMyPersonalNumbers = db.MyPersonalNumContext.Where(i => i.EmployeeId == My_Emp_Id).Select(n => n.PersonalNumber).ToList();

var GetAllPersonalCalls = from c in db.MyAllPhoneBillContext
                                      where GetMyPersonalNumbers.Contains(c.CALLED_NUMBER)
                                      select c;
```

**I get bellow error:**

> Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'double?' to 'double'

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error

Comment: OT: Are you storing phone numbers as `double`?! You might want to reconsider...

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is nullable `double` and it cannot be turned into `double` automatically.

You have to do something with nulls in the sequence of nullable types, for example:

```
IEnumerable<double> result = 
    sequence.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your database, you have a column of type double, but that datatype can be null. You cannot compare a nullable double to a non-nullable double. You might benefit from reading [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Either one variable in your code or a field in your DB is nullable (hence the '?'), that causes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a Join query bellow is my code:

```
   var GetAllPersonalCalls = from c in db.MyAllPhoneBillContext
                                  join p in db.MyPersonalNumContext on c.CALLED_NUMBER equals p.PersonalNumber
                                  where c.CALLING_NUMBER == My_Number
                                  where c.CALL_DATE.Year == currentYear
                                  where c.CALL_DATE.Month == currentMonth
                                  select new PhoneBillVM
                                  {
                                      CALLING_NUMBER = c.CALLING_NUMBER,
                                      CALLED_NUMBER = c.CALLED_NUMBER,
                                      CALL_DURATION = c.CALL_DURATION,
                                      CustomTime = c.CALL_TIME.Hour + ":" + c.CALL_TIME.Minute + ":" + c.CALL_TIME.Second,
                                      CALL_COST = c.CALL_COST,
                                      CALL_DATE = c.CALL_DATE
                                  };
```